# GoogleMap dragend event on Polygon breaks Material Angular Snackbar

Tags: google-maps, angular-material, angular-google-maps

When using the snackbar from within a GoogleMaps listener for `dragend` on a Polygon,

```
let polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
  map: this.map.googleMap,
  paths: coords.map(c => ({
    lat: c.latitude,
    lng: c.longitude
  })),
  strokeColor: `#caa052`,
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: `#ffffb1`,
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, "dragend", () => {
  this._snackBar.open("dragend");
});
```

the snackbar message gets stuck in the upper left corner and never dismisses.

Working example can be found at https://google-map-drag-breaks-snackbar.stackblitz.io/. Code can be found at https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-map-drag-breaks-snackbar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsnack-bar-overview-example.ts.

Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to use `NgZone.run` since I was not using the `map-polygon` binding.

```
constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, private _ngZone: NgZone) {}

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, "dragend", () => {
  this._ngZone.run(() => this._snackBar.open("dragend"));
});
```